# XPath query to get nodes that contain prefix to a string

Tags: xpath

How do you fetch records that contain a node that is a prefix to a string you are searching for?

XML looks like this:

```
<records>
  <record>
    <name>foo</name>
    <prefix>abc</prefix>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>bar</name>
    <prefix>def</prefix>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>bar</name>
    <prefix>abc.123</prefix>
  </record>
</records>
```

So if I have string "abc.123.xyz", I would fetch the first and third records.

Roughly translated to "/records/record[prefix[is-contained-in?('abc.123.xyz')]]"

Any XPath functions that I see work the other way around (starts-with, contains), where you specify the substring instead of the node containing the substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches record nodes in your sample:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/records/record[starts-with(./prefix, substring-before('abc.123.xyz','.'))]"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

[substring-before](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring-before.html)

Comment: Thanks.  This brought me to my answer. "/records/record[starts-with('abc.123.xyz', ./prefix)]